# Searching for numbers in a string

Tags: c++, string, search, numbers

User inputs a string in form of

> length=10 width=15

The task is to find the length's and width's value in such a string(and assign them to variables). So, how can I find those two numbers? What functions/methods should I use? Can you guys just give me an idea?

Comment: Are there *any* aspects of the problem you can address?

Comment: @ScottHunter    I'm not sure what you're talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use stringstream:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;
int main()
{

    stringstream ss;

    ss.str("length1=10 width=15 length2=43543545");

    map<string, int> resMap;
    string key;
    int val;
    while (ss.peek() != EOF) {
        if (isalpha(ss.peek())) {
            char tmp[256];
            ss.get(tmp,streamsize(256),'=') ;
            key = tmp;
        } else if (isdigit(ss.peek())) {
            ss >> val;
            resMap.insert(pair<string, int>(key,val));
        } else {
            ss.get();
        }
    }

    cout << "result:\n";
    for (map<string, int>::iterator it = resMap.begin(); it != resMap.end(); ++it) {
        cout << "resMap[" << it->first<< "]=" << it->second << endl;
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions are fun and are usually not acceptable as homework solutions for introductory classes.

`match[1]` and `match[2]` are the numerical portion of the string that you are interested in. You'll probably want to pass them to [`stoi()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) if you need to manipulate them as integers.

#### Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main() {
    std::string s("length=10 width=15");
    std::regex re("length=([0-9]+) width=([0-9]+)");
    std::smatch match;

    if (regex_match(s, match, re)) {
        std::cout << "length: " << match[1] << "\n";
        std::cout << "width:  " << match[2] << "\n";
    }
}
```

#### Output

```
length: 10
width:  15
```